# Call a function after ListView has called getView()

Tags: android, android-inflate

Is there any way that you can call a function after its getView method has been called. For example, i would like to be able to hide/show various widgets based on the size of them. For this i need to be able to query the size of the widget in the view.

My problem is that the getView method in an overwritten ArrayAdapter does not actually inflate the view so that any getWidth/getLeft/getHeight etc calls on widgets inside the View come back as 0. I was wondering, is there a way to call a function after that waits until the view has been properly inflated? Or perhaps an event binding that can be done that in effect waits until the view is fully inflated in the view?

Cheers

EDIT:

```
public class GetDataTask extends
    AsyncTask<Context, Void, FriendListAdapter> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(FriendListAdapter result) {
    friendList.onRefreshComplete();
        friendList.getRefreshableView().setAdapter(result);

        friendList.getRefreshableView().setOnItemClickListener(itself);
        friendList.getRefreshableView().getChildCount();
    }
```

This bit of code acts very strangely. The adapter is set but the getChildCount returns 0 even though the list showing on screen clearly shows ~15 things on the list. This

Comment: For reference, i am overwriting the method `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` in the class ArrayAdapter

Comment: as soon as you set the adapter your getview method will be called for the list. then after that you can perform any actions. :)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong in that case, because that's not been the case. I'll have another few tries at something

Comment: can you share some code so that we'll get to know what u have tried

Comment: Yeah, i'll try pull something together in a bit. I'll edit some weird stuff that's just happened

Comment: i guess yo can directly set friendlist.setOnItemCickListener(...)

Comment: Oh, that's because i'm using a library called PullToRefreshListView, to access the actual ListView you have to call getRefreshableView()

Comment: friendList.getRefreshaleView.getCount()
just give it a try :)

Comment: Oh god, i'm an idiot. That pretty much fixes everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the problem is just with getting the count of the items. You can tr this

```
friendlist.getRefreshableView.getCount()
```

please see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getCount%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {};
```

Comment: This is what i usually do in the case that i am just starting the activity. Would this work for when you change the adapter on a list though?

Comment: Just tried this, it doesn't get called apart from just after onCreate. Cheers for trying

Comment: look at this link please

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088738/when-the-getview-method-of-listview-gets-called-in-android/7088758#7088758][1]